# simple way of converting code to get average from multiple fields to getting MAX from multiple fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following sql to get total sales for each day of the week over three regions:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1,3,4,5,6,7) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Monday_SUM_sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1,2,4,5,6,7) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Tuesday_SUM_sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1,2,3,5,6,7) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Wednesday_SUM_sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1,2,3,4,6,7) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Thursday_SUM_sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,7) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Friday_SUM_sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Saturday_SUM_sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) NOT IN (2,3,4,5,6,7) THEN  [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Sunday_SUM_sales],
    USAsalesmanager,
    UKsalesmanager,
    ASIAsalesmanager
FROM 
    WORLDSALESDATA 
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS(USAsalesmanager, UKsalesmanager, ASIAsalesmanager)
```

Is there an easy way of converting this code from getting the total value of sales for each day of the week to getting the `MAX` of values for each day of the week? I am trying to keep the `sql query` as short as possible and prefer not to use multiple `IF` statements if possible.

Comment: Change `SUM()` to `MAX()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You would use `MAX()`, but I'm not sure why you are using `IN` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 2 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Monday_SUM_sales],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 3 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Tuesday_SUM_sales],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 4 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Wednesday_SUM_sales],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 5 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Thursday_SUM_sales],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 6 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Friday_SUM_sales],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 7 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Saturday_SUM_sales],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, [the_date]) = 1 THEN [USA_SALES]+[UK_SALES]+[ASIA_SALES] END) as [Sunday_SUM_sales],
       USAsalesmanager, UKsalesmanager, ASIAsalesmanager
FROM WORLDSALESDATA 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(USAsalesmanager, UKsalesmanager, ASIAsalesmanager)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have amended the sql query and rather than getting the maximum value out of the three sales areas (USA_SALES,UK_SALES,ASIA_SALES) I am getting the sum of the sales in those regions, so if USA_SALES = 1, UK_SALES=2 and ASIA_SALES =3, I need to get the maximum value '3' rather than the sum total value of '6'. Is there a small adjustment that could be made to the above code or would I have to have a different approach to the sql query to get MAX vaue?